# Borrowed value of RefCell does not live long enough

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I created two example codes, one using references of a Box and the other using `borrow_mut` of a RefCell and they don't work the same, to my surprise.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    a: usize,
}
fn main() {
    let m;
    let mut n = Box::new(A{a:5});
    {let a = &mut n; m = &mut a.a;}
    *m = 6;
    println!("{}", m);
    println!("{:?}", n);

    let mm;
    let mut nn = RefCell::new(A{a:5});
    {let mut aa = nn.borrow_mut(); mm = &mut aa.a;}
    *mm = 6;
    println!("{:?}", mm);
    println!("{:?}", nn);
}
```

I'm getting an error saying the `aa` borrowed value does not live long enough. &mut aa.a should be &mut usize so nothing to do with a RefCell and should work just like the Box example. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while the borrow `&mut n` is just a pure reference, `nn.borrow_mut()` is not. It returns a [`RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html) that implements `Drop` - because it needs to mark the `RefCell` as no longer borrowed after it is dropped. Therefore, the compiler can extend the lifetime of `&mut n` as it doesn't do anything when dropped, but it cannot do so for `nn.borrow_mut()` because it alters the behavior of the program.

Comment: But what exactly is making the compiler get to that realization? When I do `mm = &mut aa.a` Im getting a reference to an usize directly, so not a RefMut anymore. If RefMut gets dropped I should still have my &mut usize intact shouldn't I?

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães But you go through `aa` (via `Deref`), so you are borrowing `aa`, and you cannot use the resulting reference after `aa` is dropped.

Comment: But in the first example I'm doing the same thing with `{let a = &mut n; m = &mut a.a;}`, `a` will cease existing (if I understood it correctly it's similar to being dropped), but &mut usize will still be accessible.

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães But this is what I am saying: because the borrow `&mut n` is pure, the compiler can extend it, while it cannot extend the lifetime of `aa`.